# How to emulate vim job out_io buffer with neovim?

Tags: neovim, job-control

I'd like to make a plugin with functionality that is similar to https://github.com/ramele/agrep and `grep-edit` in emacs. That is get search results from `ag` or some other tool that supports multiline matches (otherwise quickfix and `cdo` is just as good choice I think), colorise them and group by file (`ag` do this by default) and then basically mirror any changes made in this buffer to the actual files.